# SocketIO Message not sending

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to write a small client to interface with a socketio server. Basically, I need to do the below steps in order.

1. Connect to the server. Read the message the server sends me upon connecting.
2. Parse the first message for an identifier and send another message
3. Send one last message and close the connection.

I'm using the python socketio library and am unable to do both steps 1 & 2 together (albeit I am able to do both in isolation). The message structure seems correct, so I figure this is either an error with my understanding of how socketio works or with my asynchronous logic. Can anybody help?

```
async def getConnection(url, payload):
   async with socketio.AsyncSimpleClient() as sio:
      await sio.connect(url, transports=['websocket'])

      # First block. Works as expected
      try:
         event = await sio.receive(timeout=10)
         if event:
            print(event)
      except: 
         pass

      # Works without the first block in front of this. Doesn't work with it though. 
      await sio.emit('message', payload)
      try:
         event = await sio.receive(timeout=10)
            if event:
               print(event)
      except: 
         pass
```

Comment: Guess this website is pretty useless now huh